# How can I use the output of a decision table with SUM, MIN, MAX hit policy?

Tags: sitecore-personalize, decisioning

If I set the Hit Policy as “Collect:Sum” the output in the test canvas is not what I expect.
For example my expected output from the following decision table is 3.

[image]

[image]

When i run this decision model for a customer i get the following result:
This is a list not a sum. I get this same result when the hit policy is Collect:Sum, Collect:Max, Collect:Min, Collect:Count.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The hit policy for “Collect:Sum” is working but it needs to be used with a programmable.

For example

- if you want to use the sum output of the Decision Table in a programmable or another decision table then it can be used as per usual by referencing it using the Output Reference
- if you want to use the sum output of the Decision Table in an experience then it can be passed into a programmable and then referenced in an experience as per usual

Programmable returning the output of a decision table using the Output Reference ('output')

[image]

The result in the test canvas of the Decision Table and the programmable.

[image]

Using the output of the decision model in an experience

[image]